# Need help for understanding of OAuth2

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0

Iam trying to get introduce on OAuth2 by using this working tutorial https://www.devglan.com/spring-security/spring-boot-security-oauth2-example

This tutorial is very good explained, but we have to define on two places User/Password, but why?

This is what I do not understand...

First place in AuthorizationServerConfig :

```
        configurer
            .inMemory()
            .withClient(CLIEN_ID)
            .secret(CLIENT_SECRET)
            .authorizedGrantTypes(GRANT_TYPE_PASSWORD, AUTHORIZATION_CODE, REFRESH_TOKEN, IMPLICIT )
            .scopes(SCOPE_READ, SCOPE_WRITE, TRUST)
            .accessTokenValiditySeconds(ACCESS_TOKEN_VALIDITY_SECONDS).
            refreshTokenValiditySeconds(FREFRESH_TOKEN_VALIDITY_SECONDS);
```

especially for

```
            .withClient(CLIEN_ID)
            .secret(CLIENT_SECRET)
```

Second place in the DB:

```
@Service(value = "userService")
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService, UserService {

@Autowired
private UserDao userDao;

public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String userId) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    User user = userDao.findByUsername(userId);
    if(user == null){
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Invalid username or password.");
    }
    return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), getAuthority());
}
```

Comment: The first is for the client, your application needs to connect to an identity provider (facebook etc.). So the first is for your application, whereas the second is for the users of your application.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response;

that means I will put the first one on my client application f.e. Angular?

And it is than also secure? because in javascript its readable or ??